# How to customize showing query parameter with DRF filtering (ManyToManyfield)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I hope my question is not a duplicated..

I'm building a rest API with DRF, now I'm trying to do filtering hashtag.

**The url I want** is `article/list?hashtags=dobi`

BUT I got id, like `article/list?hashtags=13`

Here is models.py:

```py
class Article(AbstractTimeStamp):
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=False)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    hashtags = models.ManyToManyField('Hashtag', max_length=200, related_name='articles', blank=True)


class Hashtag(models.Model):
    hashtag = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=True)
```

Here is my serializers.py:

```py
class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    hashtags = HashtagsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['id','title','hashtags']
```

Here is my views.py:

```py
class ArticleListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ListSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter,DjangoFilterBackend]

    search_fields = ['title']

    filterset_fields = ['hashtags']
```

How can I override it?
I tried to overriding in listapiview
`lookup_url_kwarg = ['hashtags']`

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create a new `Filterset` for filtering the field `hashtag`.

```
class HashTagFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    hashtags = CharFilter(method='filter_hashtags')

    def filter_hashtags(self, queryset, name, value):
        lookup = '__'.join([name, 'hashtag'])
        return queryset.filter(**{lookup: value})


    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['hashtags']
```

And in `ArticleListAPIView`, you need to set `filterset_class`.

```
class ArticleListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ListSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter,DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = HashtagFilter
    search_fields = ['title']
```

Comment: thank you! but it didn't work ;-; I got this error ```filter_hashtags() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given```

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `self` keyword. I changed my answer. Please try again.

Comment: Reallllly Thank you:) it worked but it's still id;-;

Comment: Oh, you wanted to search for `hashtag` field. I changed my answer. Please check again.

Comment: I have a question, why do we put this in a variable?  ```hashtags = NumberFilter(method='filter_hashtags')```  Does this hashtags variable put in Meta fields?

Comment: Doesn't it work?

Comment: yes it didn't work ;-; I changed ```NumberFilter``` to ```CharFilter``` because I want to input words myself when I filter hashtag. So I got url like ```article/list?hashtags=dobi``` but I couldn't get filtered data

Comment: I think you can just check out logs.

Comment: It works!!! I had a mistake when I input hashtag keyword. THANK YOU Metalgear!!!!!!!!!!!